# LoopBack and an admin user

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I'm working through the LoopBack docs found [here](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/LoopBack). I'm not following the docs to build the apps covered, rather, I'm applying the concepts to something of my own.

I have the following models:

1. `SuperUser`   => extends the built in `User` model
2. `Profile`     => extends the built in `User` model
3. `Account`     => a LoopBack `PersistedModel`
4. `Transaction` => a

#### Brief:

I do not want an authenticated instance `Profile` to be able to to access the endpoint `Profile GET /Profiles`. I do not want `Profile` to be able to have access to information about all of the `Profile`(s). So, I've proposed `SuperUser`, which should be able to access the endpoint `Profile GET /Profiles` through the implementation of a `Role`.

#### Standing:

This is what I have so far:

A function to create `SuperUser`, and a `Role` with `name` of `admin`. That role is then assigned to the created `SuperUser`.

```
function createSuperUser(){
  SuperUser.create([
    {email: "reubs@reubs.com", username:"reubs", password: 'password'}
  ], function(err, users) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('Created user:', users);

    //create the admin role
    Role.create({
      name: 'admin'
    }, function(err, role) {
      if (err) throw err;

      console.log('Created role:', role);

      role.principals.create({
        principalType: RoleMapping.USER,
        principalId: users[0].id
      }, function(err, principal) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log('Created principal:', principal);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

My `profile.json` where the dynamic role `$owner` is used in the `acls` to try and make sure that `Profile` can only get what it owns. Not also the inclusion of the `admin` rule in the `acls`.

```
{
  "name": "Profile",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "accounts": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "Account",
      "foreignKey": "profileId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$owner",
      "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "admin",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "find"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

#### Issue:

This setup is allowing an authenticated `Profile` to access the endpoint `Profile GET /Profiles`

#### Goal:

I only want `SuperUser` to be able to really have complete control over the `Projects` API endpoint. I.e. `SuperUser` should be able to get all `Profiles` etc.

Thanks in advance,
Reubs

Answer (score 0):

In your Profile.js file you should implement some method that accepts the current/source profile id that is attempting to make a request (which you would get from the current context). Compare the profile id being requested and the current profile id. If they match, send back the data.

Be sure to add the name of the validation method in your json. For example: `"property": "[find, yourProfileValidationMethod]"`. In addition, you can add the `"model": "Profile"` property within your json to make this rule specific to this model.

I hope this answers most of your questions. If you would like more help, please let me know.